# Expand a div to bottom of its parent container

Tags: css

I have a div `#parent` which has a `min-height:400px;`

This div contains 2 child divs, the last of which I want to expand down to the bottom of its parent, despite the amount of content inside of it.

The height of parent is fluid as content can be a lot or very small.

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="child1"><!-- content here --> </div>
     <div id="child2><!-- this div should stretch down to bottom of parent container--></div>
</div>

#parent{min-height:400px;}
```

Is this at all possible - I can't use any js hacks

Comment: If it's anything to do with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154149/min-height-with-absolute-positioning/5154462#5154462), it's *not going to happen* with pure CSS with two variable height elements.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Sorry, this doesn't actually work - the bottom div doesn't expand to fit the content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQpFk.png

As long as `#child1` has a fixed height, this is possible. So, you have:

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="child1">&nbsp;</div>
     <div id="child2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS you use is:

```
#parent {
    min-height:200px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#child1 {
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#child2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8VdV/

If `#child1` cannot have a fixed height then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky to do with just CSS.  It is possible, but it gets ugly, instead, when I need to do this, I use the [YUI Layout Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/layout/).  I am sure JQUERY also has something similar as well.  But I find this the easiest and most bug free way to do what your asking.